# How to tell when a iOS notification drop down goes away?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my app, I have a pretty standard phone number verification screen.  So the user enters their phone number then gets to a "verification" screen  like so:

[image]

The system sends them an SMS message, and they get a notification:

[image]

If the user swipes down on this notification, they get the following screen:

[image]

Now when they're done and tap on the "X" icon, they get back to the verification screen, however the keyboard has disappeared:

[image]

Under normal circumstances, you could tap on the text field and the keyboard would come back, however I'd like to save the user that step and have the keyboard reappear automatically (and besides, the text fields in this case aren't tappable anyway).

I could try using the UIApplicationDidBecomeActive notification, but I thought there might be something else more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Add textfield firstResponder in viewWillAppear().

```
 override func viewWillAppear(){

   super.viewWillAppear(true)   
   self.tfVerification.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: viewWillAppear isn't called in this case since technically it never disappears.